# How to Read First 512 Bytes of data from a .dat file in C#?

Tags: c#

H,

How to Read First 512 Bytes of data from a .dat file in C# ?
My dat files contains binary data.
I am using `File.ReadAllBytes` currently to read data from the dat file.But it Reads all the data, i want to read only first 512 bytes then break.
I need to use for loop for this or any other approach.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
try
{
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          var bytes_read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
          fs.Close();

          if (bytes_read != buffer.Length)
          {
              // Couldn't read 512 bytes
          }
     }
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
     Debug.Print(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Check out [this page](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/readbinary.html) from Jon Skeet why this approach is not a good solution.

Comment: `Stream.Read` returns a value that represents the *actual* number of bytes that was read. Ignoring it is a recipe for confusing failures.

Comment: Why close the stream explicitly? FileStream is IDisposable

Comment: Is there a chance that bytes_read != buffer.Length?

Comment: @RayChakrit whenever you read a file, a lot of things can occur behind the scenes, so IMHO it's always a good idea to double check before your code goes terribly bad :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `byte[]` variable, and [FileStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but effective approach:

```
var result = ""; //Define a string variable. This doesn't have to be a string, this is just an example.
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(openFileDailog1.FileName))) //Begin reading the file with the BinaryReader class.
{
    br.BaseStream.Seek(0x4D, SeekOrigin.Begin); //Put the beginning of a .dat file here. I put 0x4D, because it's the generic start of a file.
    result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(br.ReadBytes(512)); //You don't have to return it as a string, this is just an example.
}
br.Close(); //Close the BinaryReader.
```

`using System.IO;` enables access to the `BinaryReader` class.

Hope this helps!